# how to delete a hash with subhashes by name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my html I have:

```
<input name="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_placment_id]" />
<input name="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_id]" />
and ....
```

I'd like to delete this whole series of elements via something like this but this doesn't work:

```
  $('[name*=creative[placement_creative_attributes]]').remove();
```

What is the proper way to delete this entire hash via jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up a bit of your quotes in your example, should likely have quotes around the expected wildcard match for the `name` attribute:

```
$('[name*="creative[placement_creative_attributes]"]').remove();
```

---

In this particular case however, I'd reccommend using the carat (`^`) to select every element that has a `name` attribute that starts with the string `creative[placement_creative_attributes]`, and then `remove()` each of them from the DOM:

```
$("[name^='creative[placement_creative_attributes]']").remove();
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("[name^='creative[placement_creative_attributes]']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_placment_id]" placeholder="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_placment_id]" /><br />

<input name="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_id]" placeholder="creative[placement_creative_attributes][site_id]" /><br />

<input name="creative[site_id]" placeholder="creative[site_id]" /><br />

<button>Remove placement_creative_attributes</button>
```

Comment: cool - wasn't that familiar with `^` syntax - why wouldn't you use `*` in this case. i thought it was all items named XXX

Comment: The asterisk (`*`) token matches if the string appears *anywhere* in the attribute's value. In this case, it might not make *much* difference, but down the road if you were to arrange your data structures in a way that `creative[placement_creative_attributes]` might appear within another string (e.g., `another_data_structure[creative[placement_creative_attributes]]`), and you wouldn't necessarily want the same rules applied to the latter.